# Bedroom encouter with somebody?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> They walked through the gloomy gray afternoon to a restaurant and bar
>   over on Broadway near West 76th. Before they entered, Allie noticed
>   that the lighted time-and-temperature sign on the Apple Bank said it
>   was one o’clock, but she wasn’t at all in need of lunch. **The bedroom
>   encounter with Hedra seemed to have killed her appetite**. Intense
>   emotion did that to her, be it anger or pity.

I'm reading *Single White Female* by John Lutz.

1. I don't know what kind of restaurant and bar would have a bedroom.
2. I think "encounter" would be "somebody encounter with somebody/something". I don't understand how a bedroom encounter with a people.

Comment: Is there content *before* this paragraph? What had Allie just done in a bedroom with Hedra **before** going to the bar?

Comment: @Catija, I read it by local file. I searched it online, but can't find one. How did you find that? :)

Comment: I copied the first line into Google Search. Returned this: https://books.google.com/books?id=fJGZwYkfqcYC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%22They+walked+through+the+gloomy+gray+afternoon+to+a+restaurant+and+bar+over+on+Broadway+near+West+76th.%22&source=bl&ots=nOlma7anEo&sig=PgnAeEBig3QRm88pji4R752uk4o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOlISFwcDbAhVR7qwKHSdVB-AQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22They%20walked%20through%20the%20gloomy%20gray%20afternoon%20to%20a%20restaurant%20and%20bar%20over%20on%20Broadway%20near%20West%2076th.%22&f=false

Comment: A "bedroom encounter" literally is an encounter (presumably between two people) in a bedroom. Such "bedroom encounter" would have occurred earlier and has no relation to the bar. Because, something that *kills your appetite* would happen before some meal that you then would not want to eat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways 'bedroom encounter' could be interpreted:

- An encounter in a bedroom.
- A sexual encounter.

From the description given (and a quick Google for a plot summary), it's more likely the first one: Allie and Hedra had an emotionally draining discussion in a bedroom in their apartment, and Allie is still upset about it.

You can interpret this as saying 'the encounter with Hedra', with 'bedroom' acting as an adjective to describe which particular encounter is being referenced.

Comment: Now I understand here 'bedroom' is an adj. I have thought it was a noun.